# Conditional binding on array

Tags: swift

Is there a way to use `if let` on an array. `If` the array has a value at `index` `let` it equal this value.

```
if let view = self.view.subviews({$0.tag == 1 })[0] {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
} else {
     print("No view with tag 1")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` functionality, and use `first` instead of `[0]`, to avoid crashes if the filtered array has no elements:

```
if let view = self.view.subviews.filter{ $0.tag == 1 }.first {
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 added the [`Sequence.first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1849238-first) method, which can replace the calls to `filter` and `first` in [Cristik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617434/116862).

The advantages of `first(where:)` over `filter { ... }.first` are (a) the code becomes marginally clearer and (b) more importantly, better performance when the array is large or the closure is expensive because it stops after finding the first match.

```
if let view = self.view.subviews.first { $0.tag == 1 } {
    ...
}
```